# merge jquery repetitive code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reduce the amount of code I have on the page. I'm not a good coder in JavaScript / jQuery so bear with me.

I have the following code

```
    $('.testimonial-1').each(function(event){ 

        $(this).find('a.read-more-testimonial-1').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-1').hide();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-2').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-3').fadeIn(400).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-4').fadeIn(600).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-5').fadeIn(800).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-6').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-1').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-2').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-3').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-4').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-5').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-6').hide();
            $('.testimonial-1').addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-4');
            $('.testimonial-2').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-3').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-4').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-5').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-6').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
        }); 
    });

$('.testimonial-2').each(function(event){ 

        $(this).find('a.read-more-testimonial-2').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-2').hide();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-1').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-3').fadeIn(400).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-4').fadeIn(600).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-5').fadeIn(800).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-6').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-2').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-1').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-3').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-4').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-5').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-6').hide();
            $('.testimonial-2').addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-4');
            $('.testimonial-1').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-3').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-4').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-5').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-6').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
        }); 
    });

$('.testimonial-3').each(function(event){ 

        $(this).find('a.read-more-testimonial-3').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-3').hide();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-2').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-1').fadeIn(400).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-4').fadeIn(600).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-5').fadeIn(800).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-6').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-3').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-2').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-1').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-4').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-5').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-6').hide();
            $('.testimonial-3').addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-4');
            $('.testimonial-2').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-1').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-4').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-5').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-6').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
        }); 
    });

$('.testimonial-4').each(function(event){ 

        $(this).find('a.read-more-testimonial-4').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-4').hide();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-2').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-3').fadeIn(400).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-1').fadeIn(600).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-5').fadeIn(800).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-6').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-4').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-2').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-3').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-1').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-5').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-6').hide();
            $('.testimonial-4').addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-4');
            $('.testimonial-2').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-3').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-1').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-5').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-6').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
        }); 
    });

$('.testimonial-5').each(function(event){ 

        $(this).find('a.read-more-testimonial-5').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-5').hide();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-2').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-3').fadeIn(400).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-4').fadeIn(600).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-1').fadeIn(800).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-6').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-5').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-2').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-3').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-4').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-1').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-6').hide();
            $('.testimonial-5').addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-4');
            $('.testimonial-2').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-3').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-4').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-1').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-6').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
        }); 
    });

$('.testimonial-6').each(function(event){ 

        $(this).find('a.read-more-testimonial-6').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-6').hide();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-2').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-3').fadeIn(400).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-4').fadeIn(600).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-5').fadeIn(800).show();
            $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-1').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-6').fadeIn(1000).show();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-2').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-3').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-4').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-5').hide();
            $('.blockquote-testimonial-1').hide();
            $('.testimonial-6').addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-4');
            $('.testimonial-2').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-3').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-4').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-5').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
            $('.testimonial-1').addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
        }); 
    });
```

and I want to merge in to something like this

```
    var i;
for (i=1; i<=6; i++)
{
    $('.testimonial-'+i).each(function(event){ 

        $(this).find('a.read-more-testimonial-'+i).click(function(event){ 

            var j;
            var k=200;
            event.preventDefault();
            for (j=1; j<=6; j++)
            {
                if (i=j)
                {
                    $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-'+j).hide();
                    $('.blockquote-testimonial-'+j).fadeIn(1000).show();
                    $('.testimonial-'+j).addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-4');
                    }
                else
                {
                    $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-'+j).fadeIn(j*k).show();
                    $('.blockquote-testimonial-'+j).hide();
                    $('.testimonial-'+j).addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
                    }
                }

            });

        });
    }
```

can this be done?

Comment: This looks pretty close. (Change `if (i=j)` to `if (i===j)`.) Can you elaborate on what problem you're having with the code you're trying here?

Comment: when the Read more link is pressed, a class should change from col-sm-4 to col-sm-12 and the rest of testimonials should get back to the col-sm-4 (if any of them are in col-sm-12) and this works with the first code

and on the second part of the code my "merged code", when I press Read more, all testimonials will go in col-sm-12 instead of just the one I press Read more

Comment: Did you fix the mistake I pointed out?

Comment: doesn't work with i===j instead of i=j

Comment: When you say "doesn't work," what do you mean? What's the behavior of the code after the fix?

Comment: it does nothing, when I press the "read more" link it does nothing.

Comment: See my answer. If that doesn't help, try using some logging to understand what's going on. E.g., if my code is right, `console.log("i = " + i, "j = " + j);` inside the loop would have shown you the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code pretty much looks right. I made a couple small changes:

1. I used an anonymous function to preserve the value of `i` for that iteration inside the click handler. (Otherwise, you capture `i` itself, and by the time the code runs, `i` is presumably 7 after the loop has finished.)
2. I changed the condition to use `===` (test for equality) instead of `=` (assignment).
3. I got rid of `$('.testimonial-'+i).each(...)`, which seemed superfluous.
4. I did some minor style fixups.

My version of the code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    $('a.read-more-testimonial-' + i).click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var k = 200;
      for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
      {
        if (j === i) {
          $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-' + j).hide();
          $('.blockquote-testimonial-' + j).fadeIn(1000).show();
          $('.testimonial-'+j).addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('col-sm-4');
        } else {
          $('.initial-blockquote-testimonial-' + j).fadeIn(j * k).show();
          $('.blockquote-testimonial-' + j).hide();
          $('.testimonial-' + j).addClass('col-sm-4').removeClass('col-sm-12');
        }
      }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Lpz8840f this is the desire result and the code you wrote does not get me there :(

Comment: See my edit. (I debugged this by logging, as I suggested in the comments.)